# maximize an application windows but not cover any of the desktop icons

Tags: windows-10

I was wondering if Windows 10 has a built-in functionality to maximize an application windows but not cover any of the desktop icons.

I want to have access to my desktop icons but I also want to have my application taking up as much of the screen as possible.

I know I can manually, resize each application, but I was hoping for an automated way, so ever application opens this way.

Looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: "I was wondering if Windows 10 has a built-in functionality to maximize an application windows but not cover any of the desktop icons." - It does not.  An application is either maximized or it's not maximized.  If you want to see your desktop and have a window maximized must users just have two displays.

Comment: You can also create a new virtual desktop by pressing win+tab and clicking "New desktop" then switch between them by doing win+ctrl+right or win+ctrl+left